# Mongoose set default as empty object

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to set  the `star_info` attribute as an object type(Mixed Schema) and setting it's default value as an empty object using

```
star_info: { type : Schema.Types.Mixed, default : { }}
```

In the database, there is no field `star_info` when saving the documents. How do I get `mongoose` to set the default value?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

By default (in an effort to minimize data stored in MongoDB), Mongoose will not save empty objects to your database. You can override this behavior by setting the `minimize` flag to `false` when you create your schema.  For example:

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  star_info: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} }
}, { minimize: false })
```

Now `star_info` will default to an empty object and save to the database.

Read more at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize

Comment: I tried this but got: `Can't customize discriminator option minimize (can only modify toJSON, toObject, _id, id)`

Comment: I want the last 30 minutes of my life back

Comment: I wish it only had been 30 minutes

Comment: I want my last 4 hours back. Answered in 2015, still very useful.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind empty objects being omitted from the database, but you want them in your JSON, just use `obj.toJSON({minimize: false})`