# Changing mongoose model causes code to error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my user schema I have a property:

```
  verification: {
    phoneVerification: {
      verified: Boolean,
      code: String,
    },
```

however, if I change it to this:

```
  verification: {
    phoneVerification: {
      verified: Boolean,
      code: String,
      carrier: String,
      type: String
    },
```

It changes my Javascript output which ends up causing an error for me.

```
let user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, '-salt -password').exec();
user.verification.phoneVerification = {};
console.log(user.verification);
```

This code at first outputs:

```
{ phoneVerification: null,
  mailVerification: { verified: false, code: '1c7d55d3d2e64ae98e82' } }
```

Then ends up outputting:

```
{ mailVerification: { verified: false, code: '1c7d55d3d2e64ae98e82' } }
```

After my model has been changed.

Because of the fact that phoneVerification isn't instantiated, my code is giving me back an error.

It's very weird, what is causing this to happen?

Edit:
I'm asking why adding another subproperty to the property on the user model, I can no longer instantiate this verification.phoneVerification object to eventually save properties to it. It's not a duplicate of above question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the error or the problem is. Where did mailVerification come from?

Comment: @RobertMoskal it was defined earlier. I will post the whole property of the model

Comment: Oh you are asking why there's no phone Verification property. This is a duplicate question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose set default as empty object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188131/mongoose-set-default-as-empty-object)

Comment: That's no error. It's the way mongo works. Follow the link to see how to fix it.

Comment: I'm asking why adding another subproperty to the property, I can no longer instantiate this verification.phoneVerification object to eventually save properties to it. It's not a duplicate of above question.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: Are you updating the model without `$set` and thus overwriting the whole document?